# Workbox webpack plugin how to completely remove

Tags: javascript, webpack, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'd like to completely remove google workbox webpack plugin from my project. If I just delete corresponding lines from the webpack config, it will not help, because users already have SW installed in the browsers. If anyone experienced with it? Or at least make it work only in offline mode, I need latest site version on load.

That is my config:

```
{
    swDest: '../sw.js',
    clientsClaim: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
}
```

Comment: As workaround, I added option `exclude: [/.*/]`. It will make your SW do nothing (about caching).